# How to change preservation of recursion in a binary tree indexing?

Tags: javascript, json, recursion, binary-tree

I wrote code in JavaScript which allows genarating any binary tree (every parent has 2 children).

User can specify how many levels of the tree he wants by variable called "levels".

code:

```
function TreeNode(name, type, properties, children) {
    this.name = name;
    this.type = type;
    this.properties = properties;
    this.children = children;
}

var levels = 3;


prop = properties("Object_1");

var tree = new TreeNode("Object_1", "level_1", prop, []);

levels--;

var tempIndex = 2;

function generateArbitraryLevels(parent, levelsRemaining) {
    // last level
    if (levelsRemaining === 0) return;

    var currentLevel = parseInt(parent.type.split('_')[1]) + 1;
    var prop1 = properties("Object_" + tempIndex);

    parent.children.push(
        new TreeNode("Object_" + tempIndex++, "level_" + currentLevel, prop1, [])
    );


    generateArbitraryLevels(parent.children[0], levelsRemaining - 1);

    var prop2 = properties("Object_" + tempIndex);

    parent.children.push(
        new TreeNode("Object_" + tempIndex++, "level_" + currentLevel, prop2, [])
    );
    generateArbitraryLevels(parent.children[1], levelsRemaining - 1);

}

generateArbitraryLevels(tree, levels);
tree = JSON.stringify([tree]);
```

For example for "levels" = 3, the tree looks like:
[image]

Every object from the tree has:

**-name** - The first field from the schema, it should include ID of a object,

**-type** - The second field, it has information about object level,

**-properties** - nevermind,

**-children**.

It works fine but I really want to change objects indexing. 
The tree should look like:
[image]

So indexing should be from left to right.
How can I do that? Maybe loops will be better for that purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for `Breadth First` instead of `Depth First` that you have implemented. Check the link below to get more information about breadth first algorithm in a tree https://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/c/tree/breadth-first/

You can refer to below code for a sample implementation of your use case

```js
    const TreeNode = (name, type, properties, children) => ({
      name,
      type,
      properties,
      children,
    });
    
    const getNode = (index, level, properties) => {
      const name = `Object_${index}`;
      const type = `level_${level}`;
      return TreeNode(name, type, properties[name], []);
    };
    
    const generateTreeChildren = (node, currentLevel, maxLevels, index, properties) => {
      if (currentLevel > maxLevels) {
        return null;
      }
    
      const child1 = getNode(index, currentLevel, properties);
      const child2 = getNode(index + 1, currentLevel, properties);
    
      node.children = [child1, child2];
    
      generateTreeChildren(child1, currentLevel + 1, maxLevels, index + 2, properties);
      generateTreeChildren(child2, currentLevel + 1, maxLevels, index + 4, properties);
    };
    
    const generateTree = (maxLevels, properties) => {
      if (maxLevels === 0) {
        return null;
      }
    
      const node = getNode(1, 1, properties);
    
      generateTreeChildren(node, 2, maxLevels, 2, properties);
    
      return node;
    };

    console.info(JSON.stringify(generateTree(3, {})));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, every level should have 2^level objects and indexes in every level should be from range:  Branch to the left should include only powers of two (2^n), branch to the right should include only 2^(n+1) - 1

Comment: yes and thats what breadth first approach is for. did you tried the above code?

Comment: okay, I have changed 2 lines in your code: <code> generateTreeChildren(child1, currentLevel + 1, maxLevels, 2*index, properties);
    generateTreeChildren(child2, currentLevel + 1, maxLevels, 2*index + 2, properties); </code> and now it's working as I wanted. Thank you.

Comment: ok, in the above code properties was expected to be an object so you might need to modify that part and wherever property is used, you need to call your function

Answer (score 0):

If you add the immediate children before you add the levels below then it will be done in a breadth first rather than depth first way. I've replaced calls to `properties` with `undefined` below as it's not included in your question's code snippet.

```js
function TreeNode(name, type, properties, children) {
    this.name = name;
    this.type = type;
    this.properties = properties;
    this.children = children;
}

var levels = 3;


prop = undefined; // properties("Object_1");

var tree = new TreeNode("Object_1", "level_1", prop, []);

levels--;

var tempIndex = 2;

function generateArbitraryLevels(parent, levelsRemaining) {
    // last level
    if (levelsRemaining === 0) return;

    var currentLevel = parseInt(parent.type.split('_')[1]) + 1;
    var prop1 = undefined; // properties("Object_" + tempIndex);

    parent.children.push(
        new TreeNode("Object_" + tempIndex++, "level_" + currentLevel, prop1, [])
    );

    var prop2 = undefined; // properties("Object_" + tempIndex);

    parent.children.push(
        new TreeNode("Object_" + tempIndex++, "level_" + currentLevel, prop2, [])
    );
    
    generateArbitraryLevels(parent.children[0], levelsRemaining - 1);
    generateArbitraryLevels(parent.children[1], levelsRemaining - 1);
}

generateArbitraryLevels(tree, levels);
tree = JSON.stringify([tree]);

// Check tree is as expected
console.log(tree);
```

Comment: that solution unfortunately is not good enough That is still the same indexing - branch indexing first. It goes to the deepest level, next branch etc...  I really want to have indexing from left to right (level indexing). Branch to the left should include only powers of two (2^n), branch to the right should include only 2^(n+1) - 1

Comment: The object indexes seem to match the 2nd diagram though, ie. Object_1 is level_1, Object_2-Object_3 are level_2 and Object_4-Object_7 are level_3?

Comment: Yes, but if levels > 3 the tree is not as it should be. Indexing should be Breadth First instead of Depth First